# Returning multiple values through java sockets

Tags: java, mysql, sockets

I have these two functions, one is on client side and it sends value to server script which then should return multiple values so I can populate textboxes.

Here is what I've done:

Client side can send multiple values to server side and server side executes mysql sucessfully but I can't figure out how to return multiple values from server to client side.

Client:

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
String identifier = "getbasicinfo";
    String hostname = "localhost";
int port = 6789;



    Socket clientSocket = null;  
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    BufferedReader is = null;


    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + hostname);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + hostname);
    }

// If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data
// to the socket we have opened a connection to on the given port

if (clientSocket == null || os == null || is == null) {
    System.err.println( "Something is wrong. One variable is null." );
    return;
}

try {


    os.writeBytes( identifier + "\n" );
    os.writeBytes( userdd + "\n" );
          os.writeBytes( shop + "\n" );
        String name = is.readLine();
        String surname = is.readLine();

        System.out.println( name + "\n");
        System.out.println( surname + "\n");
         txtname.setText(name); //it returns only this value
         txtsurname.setText(surname); 


    os.close();
    is.close();
    clientSocket.close();   
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
}           
 }
```

Server side of code:

```
public void getBasicInfo(String username, String shop)
{   
       //....database code...
       stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM workers inner join shops s where idworkers=? and s.idshops=?");
       stmt.setString(1, username);
       stmt.setString(2, shop);
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next())
       {

           dname=rs.getString("name");
           dsurname=rs.getString("surname");
        }
      os.println(dname + "\n" );
      os.println(dsurname + "\n" );

        rs.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
  //Handle errors for JDBC
  se.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e){
  //Handle errors for Class.forName
  e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
  //finally block used to close resources
  try{
     if(stmt!=null)
        conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
  }// do nothing
  try{
     if(conn!=null)
        conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
  }//end finally try
  }//end try



 }
```

Comment: Have you tried flush()ing the outputstream on the server side? Also, you should probably use a protocol like JSON to send data, it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: My output stream is clean after every execution so I think there should be no problems with that. Can you show me example how should I edit this code to send and recieve JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i think u need to make some changes in client side. for example try to make a block this way:

```
  public static void sendToAll()
{
    Iterator<Socket> sockIt = sockets.iterator();
    while(sockIt.hasNext())
    {
        Socket temp = sockIt.next();
        DataOutputStream tempOut = null;
        try
        {
            tempOut = new DataOutputStream(temp.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

this block "send to all()" sends the data to all the clients connected to it.

Comment: I dont see any connection between the question and this answer, yet it got accepted. Congrats! xD

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you need some kind of collection to gather all the results. For example

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
//...
while(rs.next())
{
    list.add(dname + ", " + dsurname);
}
```

Then return this list to the client. If you got my tiny example with the List of Strings to work you might want to continue to work on a List of Object of your own Class (for example `Name`).

Comment: Any chance you can help me out and implement list in my code, just a quick example so I have something to start from?

Comment: You could add my two lines above and in your while loop. Then after you read all ResultSets you could check your list with something like `for(String entry : list) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }`

Comment: Besides that your client code is missing the part where you receive the actual data from the server. Your code only does some setup. A [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) should help you get further.

Comment: I know, I haven't posted my whole code. Thank you for your help mate.